# How to dynamic url mapping in asp.net with c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url-rewriting, web-config, url-mapping

i want to url mapping from database like dynamically. 
For Example:
I have,

> http://www.example.com/Category.aspx?cid=c001&cname=Men

and i want to ,

> http://www.example.com/Men/

Comment: Have you considered moving to ASP.NET MVC framework?

Comment: NO. i am using asp.net 3.5 framework

Answer (score 0):

This solution is pretty intense, but a valid one nevertheless.

We had the same issue in my work some years ago (before we moved to ASP.NET MVC, which I strongly recommend).

First, we made a a new ASP.NET Module (and registered it on IIS or the Web.config). This module would receive the incoming client's requests.

We built our own `HttpModule` and made it work along a **configuration file**, where we defined our valid routes, in your case `http://www.example.com/Men/`.

We would then have a list of ***managers***. These *managers* would work as a pipeline. Each manager would receive the output of the previous one.

Following this approach, our first manager was our `RewriteManager`, which handled the rewrite of the incoming request's URL, so future managers (and legacy ones) could continue on using our **aspx** URLs.

Here is an example of one of our route in our module's configuration file:

```
<configuration name="note"
               mode="1"
               urlPattern="^https?://(([a-z0-9\-]*\.)?localhost(:[0-9]+)?/((?'note_id'[0-9]+)-?(?'title'.*))$"
               rewriteUrl="/note.aspx?note_id={note_id}&amp;site={ContextInfo.site}">

  <manager type="LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers.RewriteManager, LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers"/>

  <!-- THESE MANAGERS NEED THE ASPX URL, THEY ARE LEGACY MANAGERS -->
  <manager type="LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers.FileCacheManager, LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers"/>
  <manager type="LaNacion.Hola.Web.Managers.NotaManager, LaNacion.Hola.Web.Managers"/>
  <manager type="LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers.OutputImageCacheManager, LaNacion.Framework.Web.Managers"/>

</configuration>
```

As you can see, we define our route in a **regular expression**, and recollect required information using **named groups** on the regex. We later build our legacy URL, using that information we recollected.

In you case, the `urlPattern` attribute would look like:

```
https?://(([a-z0-9\-]*\.)?localhost(:[0-9]+)?/(?'entity'[a-zA-Z]+)
```

And the `rewriteUrl` attribute wourld be:

```
/Category.aspx?cid=c001&cname={entity}
```

We do the rewriting of the URL, using the `RewritePath` method of the `HttpContext` instance:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(newUrl);
```

The future managers will then be able to extract query parameters as they have always done, making legacy managers work the same way as before.

I hope I made myself clear enough, and this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described above by @Mati-Cicero works well if you already know your rewrite rules. If you want to go this way I would also suggest the article at http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net (an old but good one).

But if you want to rewrite to URLs stored in the database, this is what I suggest:

Create a HttpModule this way:

```
public class DBRewriteModule : IHttpModule
{
    public DBRewriteModule()
    {

    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.AuthorizeRequest += new EventHandler(context_AuthorizeRequest);
    }

    void context_AuthorizeRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Rewriter rw = new Rewriter();
        rw.Process();
    }
}
```

Add it to your `web.config` file like this:

> ```
> <system.webServer>
>     <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
>     <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
>         <add name="DBRewrite" type="smartdev.web.Modules.DBRewriteModule" />
>     </modules>
> </system.webServer>
> ```

And in your rewriter cs file you should have something similar to:

```
public class Rewriter
{
    public Rewriter()
    {
    }

    public bool Process()
    {
        // get path from database based on your original path: 
        // use HttpContext.Current.Request.Path and HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString
        string substPath = "...your db logic here ...";
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath(substPath);
    }
}
```